# If statement saved inside Javascript variable

Tags: jquery, wordpress, if-statement

I have a snippet of JQuery that is being saved into a variable name that helps create a notice on the page. I am trying to change the class associated with the html element if the class has already been added to the page. This is being done in a WordPress plugin.

Below is the original and below that is my first stab at it.

```
noticeItemOuter = jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('notice-item-wrapper');
```

My try:

```
 noticeItemOuter    =  if (JQuery(".notice-item-wrapper").length > 0) {
              jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('notice-item-wrapper2');
            }else{
                jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('notice-item-wrapper');        
            }
```

I added console logs inside the if else statement and never saw them pop up.

Comment: it's `jQuery`, not `JQuery`

Comment: you mean *"if the **Element** was already added to the page"*

Comment: also, your code should be throwing you a  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai it was giving me that error once I brought it into my IDE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If statements don't exactly work like that, but you can use the ternary operator, which functions the same way, `(expression)? true statement: false statement;`

```
noticeItemOuter    =  ((jQuery(".notice-item-wrapper").length > 0)?
          jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('notice-item-wrapper2'):
          jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('notice-item-wrapper'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to assign a variable like that. Why don't you do just something like this?

```
if (jQuery(".notice-item-wrapper").length > 0) {
  noticeItemOuter = jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('notice-item-wrapper2');
} else {
  noticeItemOuter = jQuery('<div></div>').addClass('notice-item-wrapper');        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function ($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

    // Check if element already exists
    var noticeItemExists = $(".notice-item-wrapper").length;
    
    // New Element creation
    $("<div/>", {
      "class": noticeItemExists ? "notice-item-wrapper2" : "notice-item-wrapper",
      appendTo: "body" // or wherever you want to insert your element
    });

});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator